# Writing pandas dataframe into SQL server table - no result and no error

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

Here is my code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine("connection string")
conn_obj = engine.connect()

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['29199'], 'date_created': ['2022-06-29 17:15:49.776867']})
my_df.to_sql('SomeSQLTable', conn_obj, if_exists='append', index = False)
```

I also created SomeSQLTable with script:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeSQLTable(
col1 nvarchar(90),
date_created datetime2)
GO
```

Everything runs fine, but no records are inserted into SQL table and no errors are displayed. I am not sure how to troubleshoot. `conn_obj` works fine, I was able to pull data.

Comment: After creating your `engine`, set `engine.echo = True` and then look at the log output to check for `INSERT INTO [SomeSQLTable] (col1, date_created) VALUES (?, ?)`, followed by the parameter values, and then a `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's exactly the answer but I don't have the privileges of commenting right now.

First of all, the `pd.to_sql()` returns the number of rows affected by the operation, can you please check that?

Lastly, you are defining the data types in the table creation, it could be a problem of casting the data types. I never create the table through sql as `pd.to_sql()` can create it if needed.
Thirdly, Please check on the table name, there could be an issue with the pascal case in some db's.